# Swig tool and C++. Being too clever

Tags: python, swig

http://www.swig.org/papers/PyTutorial98/PyTutorial98.pdf
It comes from above link:

[image]

I know that it is an old publication so it is possible that information is outdated.

I would like to ask:

"Seems to work fine with C++ if you aren't being too clever"
What does it mean, to be too clever?

Is there known situation/case that I shuold be very careful where I am programming C++ modules and extending Python using `swig` tool?

Comment: At a guess I'd assume they're saying 'it works if your copy constructor has expected semantics' but I can't say for certain.

Comment: if you use `--wrap` with `ld` it could interfere, although that'd apply to C too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slide is strange and misleading. SWIG does not transform pass-by-value into pass-by-reference at all. Let me try to clarify by an example:

Let's say that as in the example you have the C++ function

```
double dot_product(Vector a, Vector b);
```

Now in plain C++ (no SWIG, no wrapping) you may use this function as in the following examples:

1.

```
Vector a = Vector(1,0);
Vector b = Vector(0,1);
double zero = dot_product(a, b);
```

2.

```
Vector *a = new Vector(1,0);
Vector *b = new Vector(0,1);
double zero = dot_product(*a, *b);
```

In both cases, the function is in fact called in exactly the same way using call-by-value.

SWIG wraps all objects into a structure that contains a pointer to the object, so under the hood SWIG passes pointers around for everything, and therefore uses a syntax as in the second example. But there is no conversion / transformation of call semantics going on whatsoever.

To answer your questions:

> "Seems to work fine with C++ if you aren't being too clever" What does it mean, to be too clever?

I have no idea. As stated in another answer, likely a joke.

> Is there known situation/case that I shuold be very careful where I am programming C++ modules and extending Python using swig tool?

This is a very broad question, and there certainly are pitfalls, especially related to memory management. However, this particular "transformation" is not an issue.

For reference, here is the [relevant entry in the SWIG manual](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn22). Note that it is worded differently: The *function* is transformed to accept pointers. Nothing is said about "call semantics" (since this is a non-issue).

Answer (score 3):

This PDF appears to be a copy of slides from a presentation given by David Beazley at the 7th International Python Conference. My guess is there was a joke or verbal explanation of what he meant by that phrase.

> Seems to work fine with C++ if you aren't being too clever

Here is a [link](http://www.dabeaz.com/) to his website if you want to get in touch with him and ask him directly. His twitter account is [dabeaz](https://twitter.com/dabeaz), which may (or may not) be a better way of contacting him.